# Git Repository Window in Visual Studio 2022; Not in commit date order and will not change

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

The Local History in the Git Window of VS 2022 does not appear to be sorted by commit date order and the header is not sort-able. Does anyone know how to get it to display by commit date ?

[image: Snapshot of commit sort order]

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you click the history grid header and switch to simple view, you'd be able to see the commits by date